# Run tool does not works

Tags: windows, shellexecute

When I use Windows Run tool to call my exe with argument it work fine
I did below 
cmd.exe /C "C:\ex\abc.exe" skk
Then my exe get a hit and i got skk as an argument. BUt I i did
cmd.exe /C "C:\ex\abc.exe" "sk k" then my exe does not call. Why?
But the same thing work fine in cmd line
"C:\ex\abc.exe" "sk k"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design

If more than two quote characters are present after the /C switch, then "behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving any text after the last quote character.", unless the following conditions are met:

- no /S switch
- exactly two quote characters
- no special characters between the two quote characters, where special is one of: &<>()@^|
- there are one or more whitespace characters between the two quote characters
- the string between the two quote characters is the name of an executable file.

So, when you do

```
cmd.exe /C "C:\ex\abc.exe" "sk k"
```

it's trying to execute

```
C:\ex\abc.exe" "sk k
```

which, obviously, doesn't work. If you want to run your exe with an argument containing the whitespace, try

```
cmd.exe /C C:\ex\abc.exe "sk k"
```

Or wrap the the whole command in double quotes like so:

```
cmd.exe /C ""C:\New Folder\abc.exe" "sk k""
```

Comment: Yes, it works. but what happens if my abc.exe is in "New Folder"? I need to do this cmd.exe /C "C:\New Folder\abc.exe" "sk k". This is not working. Now What I need to do.

Comment: Then wrap the whole command in double quotes (see corrected answer above)